# Sketch: export artboard *including* layout grid

Tags: export, sketch-app, grids, layout

I'm working with a 12 column layout grid in sketch, which is great. However, when I export it, the grid is nowhere to be found!

I need the grid to be visible in my png file, so that I can include it in a style guide and stakeholders can see how it fits within a 12 column grid.

Comment: I have the same need right now. I am thinking to manually create the grid and save as symbols for each screen type I design for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an actual grid of rectangles and export them with the rest of your export. The built-in grid will not export.

Whether it should be an option is a fair question, but at this point in time I'll be happy simply with Sketch not bringing my Macbook to a crawl.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screen capture (while zoomed in at 100%) of the Layout grid on an empty artboard. Then paste that into your sketch file.